# Binaural panning in Logic Pro for doppler effect?

Tags: doppler, logic

Hi, when I googled a lot trying to find free or cheap doppler plugins for logic I came across the Binaural Panning help file for Logic pro. I had never used it before and discovered that there was a doppler-button that according to the help-file:

"Enables or disables the Doppler effect—a change in the pitch of a signal perceived by a person who is moving relative to the source of the signal."

http://documentation.apple.com/en/logicpro/usermanual/index.html#chapter=27%26section=14%26tasks=true

I've tried it and can't get it to work (with the doppler), so I ask here; has someoone used it for a doppler effect? Is it even a doppler effect the way that I mean (Like waves doppler etc.)?

Thanks

//Kristoffer

Answer (score 1):

I've used the binaural panner but not for doppler

Answer (score 1):

Ive used this for a few ideas a friend of mine had for a mix:
http://wavearts.com/products/plugins/panorama/

Its pretty neat for soundscapes - but in my opinion useless for music.

I think there is a demo, depending on your definition of cheap it may or may not be - weighing in at $150 bucks.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this and it seems to work. The trick is to up the Size parameter and make sure you're in Planar mode. The Doppler effect is not very smooth in terms of pitch and other parameters such as frequency/volume dynamics are non-existant, but I can see this work for quick and dirty effects that need movement. I like that it's automation-friendly... Thanks for pointing this out. I don't think I'd have been able to find it..

Answer (score 1):

Hi, again thanks for the answers.

I tried doing as georgi described but att first I just heard very little effect. Maybe I was stupid, but I hadn't tried dragging the ball straight over the circle, I had just driven it around in circles, and therefore couldn't hear a big effect.

But now when I tried dragging it straight over, the doppler effect was there!!!

I almost feel like celebrating, because there will be at least some years until I feel that I can spend that much money on Waves or GRM tools dopppler plugins, so now I at least have some kind off doppler effect!!!

I think I can agree on that it's not very smooth, especially when it's crossing over the middle, but I think everyone sitting in Logic without a real doppler plugin should check it out...